# data.table colClasses conversion to POSIXct

Tags: r, data.table

Why doesn't the `colClasses` argument to `data.table::fread` seem to convert the `REQUEST_DATE` column to `POSIXct` in the example below? It converts the `ROW_ID` column without issue.

```
library(data.table)

txt <- "ROW_ID,REQUEST_TYPE,REQUEST_DATE
1,OTHER,2009-07-31 07:35:38
2,OTHER,2009-07-30 21:18:35
3,OTHER,2009-07-30 21:18:30
4,OTHER,2009-07-30 21:18:40
5,OTHER,2009-07-30 21:18:39
6,QUERY,2009-07-30 21:19:29
7,OTHER,2009-07-30 21:18:42
8,OTHER,2009-07-30 21:18:45
9,OTHER,2009-07-31 07:35:31
10,OTHER,2009-07-31 07:35:30
"
dt <- fread(txt, colClasses = c(ROW_ID = "character", REQUEST_DATE = "POSIXct"))
```

The typical conversion also works:

```
dt[, as.POSIXct(REQUEST_DATE)]
 [1] "2009-07-31 07:35:38 EDT" "2009-07-30 21:18:35 EDT" "2009-07-30 21:18:30 EDT" "2009-07-30 21:18:40 EDT" "2009-07-30 21:18:39 EDT"
 [6] "2009-07-30 21:19:29 EDT" "2009-07-30 21:18:42 EDT" "2009-07-30 21:18:45 EDT" "2009-07-31 07:35:31 EDT" "2009-07-31 07:35:30 EDT"
```

In this particular case I can't do `dt[, REQUEST_DATE := as.POSIXct(REQUEST_DATE)]` however because the real data has ~50m rows and many columns. The alternate syntax also doesn't seem to work:

```
dt <- fread(txt, colClasses = list(POSIXct = "REQUEST_DATE"))
```

The `data.table` help for `fread` says "A character vector of classes (named or unnamed), as read.csv. Or a named list of vectors of column names or numbers, see examples. colClasses in fread is intended for rare overrides, not for routine use. fread will only promote a column to a higher type if colClasses requests it. It won't downgrade a column to a lower type since NAs would result. You have to coerce such columns afterwards yourself, if you really require data loss."

It isn't clear to me that the `POSIXct` is considered a lower type than `character`.

I am using `data.table` version 1.10.0 .

Comment: Maybe the docs for the colClasses arg need to be updated, but it does say near the top "Dates are read as character currently. They can be converted afterwards using the excellent fasttime package or standard base functions."

Comment: Indeed, I am using the fasttime package. It converts 50m rows in about 12 seconds, which is pretty good!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Frank mentions in the comments, it looks like this is a current `data.table` limitation. I ended up using the `fastPOSIXct` function in the `fasttime` package. It converts 50m rows in about a dozen seconds on my laptop, which is quite reasonable for my use case.